# How to create a monomial plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

I want to create a function, that result will be a plot of moniomals ( degree less than "n").

I wrote the simple code.

```
Monomial=function(m){
  x=1:100
  y=1:100
  for(i in m) x2=x^m
  plot(y,x2,type="l",col="red",xlab="Arguments",ylab="Values",
       main=expression("Monomials"))
```

But for example: Monomial(3) I getting plot x^3. I need yet x^1 and x^2. How to name each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
Monomial <- function(m){
  x <- 1:100
  cols <- palette(rainbow(m))

  plot(x,x,type="l",col = cols[1],xlab="Arguments",ylab="Values",
       main=expression("Monomials"))

  for (d in 2:m){
      lines(x, x^d, type="l", col=cols[d])
  }

  legend(90, 60, legend=c(as.character(paste0("x",1:m))),
         col=cols, lty=1, cex=0.6)
}
```

You need to generate colors. This is what the `cols` variable achieves. `lines` adds a new curve to existing axes. Finally, `ledend` adds a legend to the plot.